# Calling variables defined in outer function from inner function with debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging

From the [jQuery docs javascript guide](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/):

> Because local scope works through functions, any functions defined
>   within another have access to variables defined in the outer function:

```
function outer() {
    var x = 5;
    var y = 2;
    function inner() {
        console.log( x );
        debugger; // <-- !!!
    }
    inner();
}
outer()
```

Console triggered with `debugger`:

```
> x
5
> y
ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

Since variables defined in the `outer` function can be used by the `inner` function (E.g. `x` or `y`), why is the debugger not able to call the `y` variable?

I suspect people will answer that the debugger only shows variables defined in the most inner/local scope. The reason for this being that otherwise no distinction could be made using the debugger between the inner and outer scope when inspecting a variable using the debugger in the inner function.
Additionally, every variable defined in an outer scope which is executed in the inner scope allows the debugger to access it.

But **if that is the case**, isn't there some way to still call the variable `y` from the console inside the inner function? (using a notation respectful of scope, e.g. `outer.y`)

## Edit: Debuggers in other languages

Apparently this behavior of a debugger is not limited to javascript. The Python debugger `pdb` for example behaves similarly:

```
def outer():
    x = 5
    y = 2
    def inner():
        print x
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    inner()
outer()

(Pdb) x
5
(Pdb) y
*** NameError: 'y' is not defined
```

Comment: In the sources tab, you have both Watch Expressions and Scope Variables available to inspect - as the answer James Allardice gave notes, y is never added to the Closure scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably this is an optimisation by the JavaScript engine. Since you're not referring to `y` within the inner function there is no need to hold on to it in the closure. This will allow it to be garbage collected when the outer function returns.

If you add a reference to `y` (for example `console.log(x, y)`) you can see the values of both `x` and `y` as you would expect.

> isn't there some way to still call the variable y from the console inside the inner function?

Apparently not. You could just add a reference to `y` within `inner` while debugging (it doesn't have to do anything, any reference will do).